# DataTable select distinct and sum

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a dataset `dsItemDtls` and it contains columns `Size Code` and `Quantity`.

Size Code is 41,42,41 like and quantity is like 1,2,1,2 and I am getting output like this

```
41 |42 |41 |42 |41 |
____________________
1  | 2 |1  |2  |2  |
____________________
```

but I need the Output like this:

```
41 |42
_______

4  |4
```

I have tried this code:

```
DataRow[] result = ddd.Table.Select("group by SizeCode,Quantity");
```

Comment: you can easily change your query to groupby sizecode and sum of quantity..

Comment: So where I need to modify.?

Comment: the query you use to fill the DataSet.. and that information is not included in the question

Answer (score 2):

i think following Query will help you

```
var result = from r in dt.AsEnumerable()
             group r by new { SizeCode = r["SizeCode"] } into g
             select new { SizeCode  = g.Key.SizeCode ,                           
             Quantity = g.Sum(x => Convert.ToInt32(x["Quantity"])) };
```